# missing reference error, after adding a specific citation

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing, compiling

I'm running into an error that i can't solve. After adding a particular citation, the compiler goes crazy and gives me missing reference errors. With certain citations, i don't have any error.

I'm using VScode with Latex workshop, but I'm not very good with the technical stuff behind bibtex and the different compilation engines. After some research already, I can't identify my problem.

Here is the log file when it crashes :

```
    
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'c:/Users/Loicr/OneDrive/Documents/ETSEIB/BA6 Eramus Research Project/Manuscrit_latex/PlantillaTFG.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "c:\Users\Loicr\OneDrive\Documents\ETSEIB\BA6 Eramus Research Project\Manuscrit_latex\PlantillaTFG.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/Loicr/OneDrive/Documents/ETSEIB/BA6 Eramus Research Project/Manuscrit_latex/PlantillaTFG.tex
LaTeX2e  patch level 1
L3 programming layer  (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/systeme/systeme.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/systeme/systeme.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/draftwatermark/draftwatermark.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/transparent/transparent.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyref/fancyref.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/varioref.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/commath/commath.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrextend.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))))

LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/tgpagella.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hologo/hologo.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/t1qpl.fd) (./PlantillaTFG.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx) (./PlantillaTFG.bbl) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty)) [1{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}  ] [2]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
 
                   \relax 
l.120 \clearpage
                \null\newpage [1]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
 
                   \relax 
l.120 \clearpage\null\newpage
                              [2] [3] [4] [5] (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/ts1qpl.fd) [6]
Overfull \hbox (2.3554pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 190--195
\T1/qpl/m/n/10.95 The ve-hi-cle be-hav-ior is mod-eled with a Carte-sian dy-namic and Curvature-based model (CDCB).
[7] [8 ] [9]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:rwd2' on page 10 undefined on input line 291.

[10  ]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:rwd3' on page 11 undefined on input line 301.

[11  ] [12  ] [13   ]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:rwd1' on page 14 undefined on input line 380.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:frictionf' on page 14 undefined on input line 381.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)
Overfull \hbox (4.02882pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 413--413
[]\T1/qpl/m/n/10.95 Javier Iba�ez-Guzm�n et al. ``Au-tonomous Driv-ing: Con-text and State-of-the-Art''. In: \T1/qpl/m/it/10.95 Hand-

Overfull \hbox (15.39946pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 413--413
\T1/qpl/m/it/10.95 book of In-tel-li-gent Ve-hi-cles\T1/qpl/m/n/10.95 . Ed. by Azim Es-kan-dar-ian. Lon-don: Springer Lon-don, 2012, pp. 1271^^U
c:/Users/Loicr/OneDrive/Documents/ETSEIB/BA6 Eramus Research Project/Manuscrit_latex/PlantillaTFG.tex:413: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
 Design &
                    Development of an Aerodynamic Package for an FSAE Race Car
l.413 ...raphy[heading=bibintoc, title=References]
                                                  
[14] [15] (./PlantillaTFG.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `PlantillaTFG.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                PlantillaTFG
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information){c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-ec-sc.enc}{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-ec.enc}{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-ts1.enc}
Output written on PlantillaTFG.pdf (17 pages, 2227367 bytes).
SyncTeX written on PlantillaTFG.synctex.gz.

Transcript written on PlantillaTFG.log.
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'PlantillaTFG.bbl'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'PlantillaTFG.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Reference `eq:frictionf' on page 14 undefined on input line 381
  Reference `eq:rwd1' on page 14 undefined on input line 380
  Reference `eq:rwd2' on page 10 undefined on input line 291
  Reference `eq:rwd3' on page 11 undefined on input line 301
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 5 reference(s)
Latexmk: Examining 'PlantillaTFG.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'PlantillaTFG.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf "-outdir=c:/Users/Loicr/OneDrive/Documents/ETSEIB/BA6 Eramus Research Project/Manuscrit_latex" "c:/Users/Loicr/OneDrive/Documents/ETSEIB/BA6 Eramus Research Project/Manuscrit_latex/PlantillaTFG"
```

Here is the example, if you add `\cite*{phdthesis}` it fails to compile

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, titlepage, twoside]{article}

%Cedit a tots els estudiants futurs
\title{Plantilla Per a TFG-TFM ETSEIB}
\author{Andrea Serrano Costafreda i Bartomeu Costa Prats }
\date{gener 2019}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Language and font encodings
%\usepackage[english]{babel} %spanish, english, ...
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{4mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{60pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, inner=3cm, outer=2cm, footnotesep=1cm, heightrounded]{geometry}


%% Useful packages
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{research_manuscript.bib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{textcomp} %podem escriure ``o'' amb la comanda \textdegree també € amb \texteuro
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym} %tb official en lloc de ``gen''
\usepackage[section]{placeins} %Evita que les figures saltin de secció
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{scrextend}%Indentar un bloc sencer
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{hologo}


%%Comença pàgina nova per cada Secció SI hi ha alguna cosa escrita a la anterior

%%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\cleardoublepage}


%%Caps de pagina i peus (E/O (even/odd), L/C/R (left/center/right) y H/F (header/footer))
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[ER]{Memòria}
\fancyhead[OL]{Modelling and Simulation of autonomous vehicle}
\fancyhf[ELH, ORH]{page \thepage}
%\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[EL, OR]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ETSEIB.png}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\raggedbottom

\SetWatermarkText{\hspace{9mm}\transparent{0.15}\includegraphics[scale=1]{ETSEIB.png}}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkLightness{1}
\DraftwatermarkOptions{stamp=false}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H] %Recorda fixar la posició de les figures si no
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{ETSEIB.png}
    \caption{Una imatge del logo de l'ETSEIB}
    \label{fig:ETSEIB} %Si es posen les etiquetes de forma ordenada, la vida es més fàcil...
\end{figure}
\newpage

%------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}\label{introduction}
\subsection{Motivation}
    Self-driving cars have interested the scientific community for a long time, with the first experiments being made 
    around the 20s \cite*{phantom_auto}. It took time to refine the technologies with various experiments
    through the years. A major advancement was made in the 80s when a car was able to self-drive on 
    a highway at 30 km/h, avoiding obstacles and driving through the night too \cite*{80_breakthrough}. 
    The research for the use of autonomous cars on the road continued through various funding projects and with companies such as 
    Waymo or Telsa to the present day. The autonomous racing car scene is more recent
    and started in 2016 with competition such as Roborace \cite*{wiki:Roborace} and the Formula Student driverless
    \cite*{wiki:Formula_Student}. Since autonomous racing is relatively new, there is still a lot of improvement to 
    be made in this regard. One of the approaches is to observe and improve the correlation between the autonomous car's data 
    from a specific test and the same test input in a simulator. This will be the focus of this project.


%------------------------------------------
\section{The Project}

    However, this control method needs accurate measurements from the system and the explicit governing equations of the system.
    In our case, the motion of the car is derived from the bicycle model, a simplified model of what a real car would be, but it 
    is a suitable approximation that fits a variety of vehicle \cite*[][p.246]{Ibanez-Guzman2012}. It is done such to the computational cost of running the MPC.
\section{test}
\subsubsection{The governing equations}
    The vehicle behavior is modeled with a Cartesian dynamic and Curvature-based model (CDCB). 
    This contains a kinematic model to locate the car with respect 
    to a fixed reference frame, and a dynamic model where the reference frame is the car itself. In this project, 
    only the dynamic model will be simulated, and the solved equations give us the velocities $v_x$ and $v_y$, 
    and the rotational velocity about the z-axis, $r$. 
    
    Here are the differential equations of the MPC longitudinal + lateral, this is the original model used in the microcontroller

    \begin{align}
        F_f &= C_{rolling} + \frac{1}{2}A \rho_{air} C_d v_x^2 \label{eq:frictionf}
    \end{align}

    The simplified version, the MPC lateral: 
    \begin{align}
        \dot{v}_y &= \frac{1}{m}(F_{y,R} + F_{y,F}  \cos  \delta - mv_xr) \\
        \dot{r} &= \frac{1}{I_z}(F_{y,F} l_F  \cos  \delta - F_{y,R}l_R + M_z) 
    \end{align}
    The longitudinal coordinate $\dot{v}_x$ is given as an input parameter in this case. 
    



\subsection{Car Data}
\subsubsection{Simulation phase}

    \begin{align} 
        \dot{v}_x &= \frac{1}{m}(F_m - F_{y,F}  \sin \delta + mv_yr - F_f) \label{eq:rwd1} \\
        \dot{v}_y &= \frac{1}{m}(F_{y,R} + F_{y,F}  \cos  \delta - mv_xr)  \label{eq:rwd2} \\
        \dot{r} &= \frac{1}{I_z}(F_{y,F}  \cos  \delta l_F - F_{y,R}l_R) \label{eq:rwd3}
    \end{align}

\subsubsection{Optimization phase}

    \begin{equation}
        S = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} r_i^2 \quad \text{with} \quad r_i = y_i - f(x_i,\theta_1,\theta_2)
    \end{equation}

    Where $y_i$ are the xVelocity points from the current run that needs optimization. $f$ is the simulated differential equation \eqref{eq:rwd1}, 
    $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the coefficients $C_{rolling}$ and $C_d$, respectively, that are in the $F_f$ term \eqref{eq:frictionf}.

    The starting point of the optimized coefficients is their initial values, $C_{rolling} = 0.45$ and $C_d = 0.8727$. The MATLAB function 
    \textbf{patternsearch} is used to find the best parameter, by trying different $\theta_{1,2}$ within a certain range and gives 
    the result where the $S$ is minimal. To obtain more interesting results, each run was optimized in two different ways.
    At first, there is a certain variation range for both coefficients: $\theta_1 \in [0.3 \; 0.6]$ and $\theta_2 \in [0.6 \; 1.3]$. 
    The chosen range for $\theta_2$ is justified by the numerous aerodynamic feature the car has to produce downforce.




    %------------------------------------------



%INICI BIBLIOGRAFIA

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=References]

\end{document}
```

and the bibliography :

```
@article{phantom_auto,
  author          = {},
  journal         = {The Milwaukee Sentinel},
  number          = {},
  title           = {'Phantom Auto' will tour the city},
  volume          = {},
  year            = {1926}
}
@ARTICLE{80_breakthrough,
  author={Turk, M.A. and Morgenthaler, D.G. and Gremban, K.D. and Marra, M.},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence}, 
  title={VITS-a vision system for autonomous land vehicle navigation}, 
  year={1988},
  volume={10},
  number={3},
  pages={342-361},
  doi={10.1109/34.3899}}

@Inbook{Ibanez-Guzman2012,
author="Iba{\~{n}}ez-Guzm{\'a}n, Javier
and Laugier, Christian
and Yoder, John-David
and Thrun, Sebastian",
editor="Eskandarian, Azim",
title="Autonomous Driving: Context and State-of-the-Art",
bookTitle="Handbook of Intelligent Vehicles",
year="2012",
publisher="Springer London",
address="London",
pages="1271--1310",
abstract="Vehicles are evolving into autonomous mobile-connected platforms. The rationale resides on the political and economic will towards a sustainable environment as well as advances in information and communication technologies that are rapidly being introduced into modern passenger vehicles. From a user perspective, safety and convenience are always a major concern. Further, new vehicles should enable people to drive that presently can not as well as to facilitate the continued mobility of the aging population.",
isbn="978-0-85729-085-4",
doi="10.1007/978-0-85729-085-4_50",
url="https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-85729-085-4_50"
}

@misc{wiki:Roborace,
  author = "Wikipedia",
  title = "{Roborace} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
  year = "2023",
  howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Roborace&oldid=1144900913}},
  note = "[Online; accessed 12-May-2023]"
}

@misc{wiki:Formula_Student,
  author = "Wikipedia",
  title = "{Formula Student} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
  year = "2023",
  howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Formula\%20Student&oldid=1143457763}},
  note = "[Online; accessed 12-May-2023]"
}


@phdthesis{phdthesis,
author = {Oxyzoglou, Ioannis},
year = {2017},
month = {05},
title = {Design & Development of an Aerodynamic Package for an FSAE Race Car},
doi = {10.13140/RG.2.2.24595.37920/1}
}
```

I have double checked the spelling mistakes already but I'm stuck.
Thanks a lot

Comment: you  have an & in the bibentry, change that to ``\&``

Comment: Oh my god that was it, it's functioning now thank you a lot

Comment: Yes, it solved the issue, just using  `\&`